# Different log level in source files with Lumberjack

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nslog, cocoalumberjack

I started using the [Lumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack/) logging framework. It requires an integer variable called `ddLogLevel` to be defined wherever I call one of the log macros. I could write

```
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_INFO
```

at the top of every file to achieve this. However I'd prefer not to write anything, except the log macros, just as I would with `NSLog`. I can do this by defining the above variable in the [prefix header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_header) of my project. The problem with this approach is, that if I want to use a different log level in some of my files, then I can't redeclare that static variable.

Comment: Is there a windows version for lumberjack ? or something similar that can send logs created by nlog to logstash ?

Answer (score 5):

Using DynamicLogLevels allows you to accomplish the task of assigning different log levels in different files. Check it out: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack/wiki/DynamicLogLevels.